# DeserializeObject results in blank variable C#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

I'm trying to extract the values of `"name"` and `"score"` from the below JSON response:

```
 "categories": [
    {
      "name": "people_",
      "score": 0.6640625
    },
    {
      "name": "people_portrait",
      "score": 0.33203125
    }
  ]
```

My current C# code to manage this is:

```
public class Category
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double score { get; set; }
    }
```

...

```
string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Category>(contentString);

Console.WriteLine(r.name);
Console.WriteLine(r.score);
Console.ReadLine();
```

But when I try and print the result to the console a blank response is given. I have also check the debugger and `name` is populated with `null` and `score` is populated with `0`.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should Deserialize a List<Category> not a single Category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In json string, `categories` is an list of `JObjects`, so you can use @Roman's approach to solve your problem or try mine,

Here is my approach,

Create one root class called as Categories,

```
public class Categories 
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "categories")]
   public List<Category> ListOfCategory {get; set;}
}
```

Your `Category` class,

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Score { get; set; }
}
```

Now, deserialize using below code

```
var categories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Categories>(contentString);
```

Now you can iterate though `ListOfCategory`,

```
foreach(var item in categories.ListOfCategory)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Name : {item.Name} \t Score: {item.Score}");
}
```

POC: [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NDjDb0)

Comment: you don't actually need attribute JsonProperty if properties have the same name

Comment: @RomanMarusyk, I understood your comment and updated my code accordingly